# Cannot bind primeng datatable

Tags: primeng

I am new with priming (2.0.3). I have an Angular 2 program that has a public array of products.

```
private initProductListloaded(res: product[])
{
// Public array of productList
this.productList = res;
}
```

Here is the HTML code

```
<div *ngIf="showProductGrid" style="height:400px;">
   <p-dataTable [value]="productList" [rows]="10">
     <p-column field="Sku" header="Year"></p-column>
     <p-column field="Description" header="Brand"></p-column>
   </p-dataTable>
</div> 
<select name="wwindustry" style="width:100%"
   [(ngModel)]="wselectedIndustry">
      <option *ngFor="let c of productList" 
       [value]="c.Sku"> c.Description}}</option>
</select>
```

The dropdown wwindustry is for test purposes only to see if the array of productList has any data from inside the html. Everything that I tried failed to generate the datatable

Answer (score 0):

If you have field sku and Description in your productList it must show. Make sure u have imported the data table from primeng in your module.ts file.

```
import {DataTableModule} from 'primeng/primeng';
```

And also if *ngIf="showProductGrid" is false that is if showProductGrid==false then the whole div won't be rendered in DOM. Make sure value showProductGrid is true or it has got some value.

I hope these tips may help u

Comment: The import from priming is already included. I tried to execute a sample for the data table from primeng and I got the same results.

Comment: The am beinning to suspect that my HTML is wrong? Here is the HTML that I am using.

Comment: <body>
    <!--<my-app>Loading AppComponent content here ...</my-app>-->
    <my-search ng-version="4.0.1">
<p-datatable>
    <p-column field="vin" header="Vin"></p-column>
    <p-column field="year" header="Year"></p-column>
    <p-column field="brand" header="Brand"></p-column>
    <p-column field="color" header="Color"></p-column>
</p-datatable>

</my-search>
</body>

Comment: [Check here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43220338/creating-a-table-based-on-json-object-javascript/43222916#43222916)      i have answered similar question here just try in that way

Comment: What value do u send to your p-datatable ? can u add your component part in question?